# Image not showing on iPad d3js

Tags: javascript, ipad, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3js along with AngularJS in an iPad webapp. When running on Safari/Chrome everything looks good, but when running on the iPad the images I append with d3js do not show.

Here is my JS:

```
directive('zoomScreen', [function() {
    return{   
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {   
    var width = 1024,
    height = 660;
var offset= [{"xoff":-20,"yoff":10,"swipe_class":"left"},{"xoff":-80,"yoff":0,"swipe_class":"right"},{"xoff":0,"yoff":-80,"swipe_class":"left"},{"xoff":50,"yoff":0,"swipe_class":"left"}];
var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g");
var back = svg.append("image")
         .attr("class", "logo")
         .attr("x", 375)
         .attr("y", 175)
         .attr("xlink:href", "../images/brain-back.png")
         .attr("height", 300)
         .attr("width", 300)
         .style("fill", "transparent")
         .style("stroke", "black")     
         .style("stroke-width", 1)
         .on("click", outClicked);
var image = svg.append("image")
         .attr("class", "logo")
         .data([offset[0]])
         .attr("x", 485)
         .attr("y", 175)
         .attr("height", 90).attr("width", 90)
         .attr("xlink:href", "../images/image1.png") 
         .style("stroke", "black")     
         .style("stroke-width", 1)
         .on("click", clicked);
var image2 = svg.append("image")
         .attr("class", "logo")
         .data([offset[1]])
         .attr("x", 545)
         .attr("y", 255)
         .attr("height", 90).attr("width", 90)
         .attr("xlink:href", "../images/image2.png")    
         .style("stroke", "black")     
         .style("stroke-width", 1)
         .on("click", clicked);
```

And my HTML:

```
<zoom-screen>
<svg class="accel"></svg>
</zoom-screen>
```

The strange thing is the iPad knows there are elements there, because it allows me to highlight and click them, but it doesn't show the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was [convert image to base 64 string](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter). So I just set the string as a var and had my xlink:href pointing to the var instead of the location. ex:

```
var image1 = "data:foobase64stringhere";

.attr('xlink:href',image1)
```